# CI controller for loading pages into iframe

Tags: php, codeigniter, iframe

I want to implement a new module into a site, which is made with CI. I am an absolute newbie with CI and I can not figure out how to create the controller ant the view files. I need the new content to be loaded into an iframe in the current site. So far I have:

controller:

```
class Module extends Controller {

    function __construct() {
            parent::Controller();

    }

    function index() {
            $this->common->loadView('module/module');
    }
}
```

view:

```
<iframe src="/new_module/index.php" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="NO" frameborder="0" >An iframe capable browser is required to view this web site.</iframe>
```

route:

```
$route['module/(:any)'] = "module/$1";
```

site structure:

```
resources/
system/
....
new_module/
new_module/index.php
new_module/page1.php
new_module/page2.php
```

Links should be:

```
http://mydomain.com/module/page1
http://mydomain.com/module/page2
```

The link are outside of the iframe and the content should load inside the iframe. So, the iframe src should be changed dynamically.

Obviously, it does not work. Could someone with more experience with CI tell me how it 
should be done?

Thank you!

Comment: Your iframe source will be what you display initially, the new content will be decided by your links. You need to specify your iframe `name="myframe"` with the TARGET attribute from your link `<href="newpage" target="myframe">`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the frame to change dynamically, just set the target of the link to the iframe:

```
<a href="/pages/page/1" target="targetFrame">Page 1</a>
<iframe id="targetFrame" src="" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="NO" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

As I understand, by default, Codeigniter does not have "modules". That is unless you are using a CMS or somesuch that is built on top of CI in which case you'd need to specify that.

Otherwise, just use controllers correctly to get what you want.

```
class Pages extends Controller{

    public function page($id='')
    {
        switch $id{
            case 1:
                $data['pageData']='foo';
            break;
            ...
        }
        $this->load->view('page_view',$data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I cant use the target method in links only, because the iframe does not exists on each page. So if click on the following link: /pages/page/1 it should pass the page url dynamically to the iframe src.

Comment: Well you can set the target on the href to the frame on pages where the frames exist via javascript, or you could use php logic in your view file to set the target. e.g. `<?php if($framePage){$target='frameID';}?>` Please mark the question answered if it's answered so others can find it. Or reply with your own correct answer and mark that as the solution. Thanks.